# submit button in rails app is not using twitter bootstrap styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a view with a `form_for` and it has a submit button.  I would like the submit button to be styled using twitter bootstrap rails gem (which I have successfully installed into the rails project.)  However the the button isn't being styled for whatever reason, and the text in the button appears different from I specified in the argument.

The source for the view, `new.html.erb`

```
<div id="sign_up">
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
     <!-- <%= f.label :email %> --><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'input-xlarge', placeholder: 'email' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
     <!-- <%= f.label :password %>--><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'input-xlarge', placeholder: 'Password' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
     <!-- <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>--><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'input-xlarge', placeholder: 'Password confirm' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-large' "Sign Up" %></div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Right now the form looks like the following,

[image: simple form]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%= f.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-large' "Sign Up" %>`

Should be:

`<%= f.submit "Sign Up", class: 'btn btn-large' %>`